# Counting Letters

Tags: java, string, count, duplicates

I am having some difficulties in finishing this piece of code. Basically, I have to count the amount of times a letter should appear in a given string. For example, ABA should output the following

```
"A appears 1 times"
"B Appears 1 times"
"A Appears 1 times"
```

However the following code that I wrote does the following (It is part of a method)

```
public static char[] counter(char[] original, char[] manipulated) {
    int counter =0;
        for (int i=0; i<manipulated.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<original.length; j++) {
                if (original[j] == manipulated[i]) {
                    counter++;
                } else {
                    
                }
            }
            System.out.println(manipulated[i] + " appears " + counter + " times");
            counter = 0;
        }
    
    return manipulated;
}
```

The output is this:

```
"A appears 2 times"
"B appears 1 times"
"A appears 2 times"
```

Which is not wrong, but that is not how I want it. So could you please assist me on this as soon as possible. I know that I am suppose to reset some variable but I am not sure where to actually reset it.

*Some notes:
The variable manipulated is just the string that contains no duplicates so
original would be abaa and manipulated would be aba :)

Comment: "Which is not wrong, but that is not how I want it" - and how do you want it?

Comment: The way you describe it being how you want, it's simply just a matter of iterating through a character array and printing that it appears (since it's implied it appears once for each time you see it). Otherwise, counting characters is best done by incrementing a counter for each _unique_ character you see, so that you don't end up printing the count for a repeated character more than once.

Comment: @alfasin I want it like this. If the input is "AABA" it should say "A appears 2 times, B appears 1 time, and A appears 1 time". The way my code is that it prints out  "A appears 3 times, B appears 1 time, and A appears 3 times"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your expected behaviour is just "print out the number of times each character appears in a row" then I am not sure why you need the `manipulated` variable at all. Your current code just accepts it as an argument and then returns it unchanged.

So unless I am misunderstanding the problem it could be a much simpler matter of:

```
void showConsecutiveCharacterCounts(char[] input) {
    int consecutiveCount = 0;
    /* iterate through all chars */
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        /* increment count - will be 1 first time */
        consecutiveCount++;
        /* if we are at the end of a sequence of chars
           I.e. end of input OR next char does not match */
        if (i == input.length - 1 || input[i] != input[i + 1]) {
            /* print previous sequence */
            System.out.println(input[i] + " appears " + consecutiveCount + " times");
            /* and reset count */
            consecutiveCount = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay your code works. But I don't want to use it unless I understand it completly. Could you please explain in detail where your logic is in this piece of code? I would really appreciate it. Thank you. (Commenting on the code would be helpful)

Comment: Ok will add some comments explaining it

Comment: @Tahalilmorsilin you understand Alexander's code and you don't understand this 6 line simple & intuitive method ?

Comment: No where did I say that I understood Alexander's code. I simply stated that his piece of code works too (I tested his code in Eclipse). But I prefer this one because its seems indeed much simpler.

Comment: @Tahalilmorsilin Sorry I'd misunderstood your comment. Thanks for accepting this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how many times the same character appear in a row, you could change your code to

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(counter("AAACCAAAAAAAB"));
  }

  public static String counter(String s) {
    int counter = 0;
    int j;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ) {
      j = i;
      char c = s.charAt(i);
      for (; j < s.length(); j++) {
        if (counter == 0) {
          sb.append(c);
        }
        if (c == s.charAt(j)) {
          counter++;
        } else {
          break;
        }
      }
      System.out.println(s.charAt(i) + " appears " + counter + " times");
      counter = 0;
      i = j;
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
```

**UPDATE** changed the code so that you do not need to provide two char[] - now you input any String like "AAACCAAAAAAAB" (aka 'original') and the char[] formerly known as 'manipulated' will be returned by the method.

Result:
`A appears 3 times
C appears 2 times
A appears 7 times
B appears 1 times
ACAB`

Comment: This really doesn't work, because when I input AAAABCCAADEEEE, the whole program goes into a loop. @Alexander

Comment: When I call this code with `counter(new char[] {'A','A','A','A','B','C','C','A','A','D','E','E','E','E'}, new char[] {'A','A','A','A','B','C','C','A','A','D','E','E','E','E'});`, I get `A appears 4 times
B appears 1 times
C appears 2 times
A appears 2 times
D appears 1 times
E appears 4 times`. Isn't that what you wanted? have you tried my code?

Comment: For some reason, its not working for me. I think its because it is the way your syntax are. Could you write it again where its in basic java language? For example, I don't understand how your for loop is set up. Thank you

Comment: Probably it doesn't work four you, because manipulated and original are different char[]s. What I'm doing is: The inner loop (j) only iterates over all characters starting at the current position of `i` and only increases the count if both chars are the same (counting consequent characters only). as soon as a different char is found, the inner loop is exited - that's why `aab` counts as two a's, but `aba` counts as one a (two times).

Comment: Yes they are. Manipulated is just the version of Original that contains no duplicates. So if original is "AABA", the manipulated would be "ABA". Is there any way to do it now?

Comment: I've updated my code - is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes! that works too. Thank you so much, I appreciate your time and effort into helping me.